# How to restore working directory to given commit without affecting repository state?

Tags: git

I want to restore whole content of my working directory to the one saved in certain commit, but without making ANY changes to repository state - so, no `detached head state` please, because it makes my own head busy with irrelevant stuff, when all I want is basic `restore this folder contents from that backup`.

I am newbie in git and Im trying my best to not make this post a git rant, but for God's sake, why there is no `--wdironly` switch (or something like that) for git checkout command?

Why HEAD reassignment is mandatory?

The lack of simple "git restore" equivalent is so inconvenient, counterintuitive and frustrating that I found myself asking: "Why am I even using this? It has such an overhead in usage and I cant even utilize it to do the simplest task I wish for."

#### Anyway, here is the deal:

Assume there are 2 commits in master branch.

There may be some other branches out there, but we will focus on this one. The commits are: "First" and "Second", with "Second" being newest one, obviously.

I have also some trash in my working directory that I dont care for, so its contents may be safely erased before "restoring the backup".

However, there may be some precious data in my Index, so please, dont touch it if possible.

Now:

I want to take all the files that "First" commit contains and copy them to my working directory.
Thats it.

How can I fulfill this "unusual desire"?

Comment: @msw Umm... you did read my post before asking this question, rigtht? Especially the part about `detached head` may give you a clue whats wrong with `git checkout First` ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, now since I found the answer myself I realized that was a poor question.

Anyway, for your convenience - present and future newbies out there - here is the git command I was looking for:

`git checkout <given commit SHA> *`

Notice asterisk at the end of the command. Since `git checkout <commit> <filename>` restores selected file, the asterisk is just a wildcard for "all files".

Answer (score 0):

> I want to take all the files that "First" commit contains and copy them to my working directory.

You can use `git cherry-pick <sha1>` to add the desired commit to your current branch

[image]

---

> I want to restore whole content of my working directory to the one saved in certain commit, but without making ANY changes to repository state

```
# checkout new branch from a given commit
# and switch to this branch 
git checkout -b new_branch 7cd6289
```

---

> I have also some trash in my working directory that I dont care for, so its contents may be safely erased before "restoring the backup".

```
# clean all your uncommitted files
git clean -Xfd
git clean -xfd
```

> #### -x (lower case)
>
> Don’t use the standard ignore rules read from .gitignore (per directory) and $GIT_DIR/info/exclude, but do still use the ignore rules given with -e options. This allows removing all untracked files, including build products.
>
> This can be used (possibly in conjunction with git reset) to create a pristine working directory to test a clean build.
>
> #### -X (upper case)
>
> Remove only files ignored by Git. 
>   This may be useful to rebuild everything from scratch, but keep manually created files.

Comment: I feel like you slightly misunderstood my problem.
I need to restore contents of my `working directory` to state saved in one of the commits - I dont want any new commits in any branch.
However, your advice about `git checkout -b new_branch 7cd6289` born some script idea in my mind:

`git checkout -b tmp <given commit>`
`git checkout master`
`git branch -d tmp`

Comment: It still needs some serious improvements, such as replacing tmp with some much more uniqe name and returning to previous branch - not necessarily master, but: It simulates exaclty what I want - restores contents of my `working directory` to state of given commit, without moving my HEAD anywhere. Now the only thing I need is to give life to this idea... could you recommend me some git sripting tutorial?

Comment: Ok, what is the tmp?

Comment: tmp is name for temporary branch - the one that gets removed once I have my working directory restored.